# Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp

Tags: python, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, gyp

**MacOS Monterey v12.6**

Node Version **v20.2.0**

**Installed Version:**

```
pyenv --version
  pyenv 2.3.18

python2 --version
  Python 2.7.18

python3 --version
  Python 3.9.6

python --version 
  Python 3.9.6
```

**~/.zshrc**

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
# eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
# Python Version Manager
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pyenv/bin"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Runnning `yarn install` in console, full error logs:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > stimulus-sortable@3.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@hotwired/stimulus@^3.1.1".
warning " > stimulus-sortable@3.3.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@rails/request.js@^0.0.6".
warning " > stimulus-sortable@3.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "sortablejs@^1.15.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⠐ fsevents
[-/4] ⠐ waiting...
[3/4] ⠐ node-sass
error /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.2.0/bin/node /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.2.0/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@20.2.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /Users/testuser/.pyenv/shims/python2
gyp verb check python version `/Users/testuser/.pyenv/shims/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 20.2.0
gyp verb command install [ '20.2.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "20.2.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 20.2.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 20.2.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /Users/testuser/.pyenv/shims/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/testuser/.node-gyp/20.2.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/testuser/.node-gyp/20.2.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/testuser/.node-gyp/20.2.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp: Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/testuser/apps/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v20.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

Comment: have same issue, upgraded fro node 18 to 20 this error is showing...for me internally its using node-gyp v4.0.0, unsure if this version is incompatible with node 20